# Numeric+deciml keypad for iOS using type="text"

Tags: angularjs

Hi i have to show numeric keypad with decimal point  for my angularJs application in iOS device.I am using a text field with type="text".If i use type="numeric" i am facing problem while restricting the values to that field.
is there any easier way to fix the issue using type="text" and without using custom keypad.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: No . designed a custom keyboard